# Stops setInterval function from executing after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that checks the DOM for a class (.discount__value) every 2 seconds and append an HTML code if it does find it.

```
        var discountWDollar = $(".discount__value:last").text();
        var discount1 = discountWDollar.replace(/\$/g,''); //remove $ sign
        var discount = Math.abs(discount1); //convert to positive number

        var cartSubTotalWDollar = $(".cart__subtotal").text();
        var cartSubTotal = cartSubTotalWDollar.replace(/\$/g,''); //remove $ sign

        newTotal1 = cartSubTotal - discount; //new total
        var discountedTotal = newTotal1.toPrecision(4); //add decimal number(centavo)


        var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
            if ($(".discount__value")[1]) {
                $(".cart-subtotal-wrapper").append("<div class='newTotalLabel'><span class='label'>Total on Check Out</span> <span class='value'>$"+discountedTotal+"</span></div>");

            clearInterval(checkExist);
        } else { 
            console.log("retry");
        }
    }, 2000); // check every 2secs
```

The code works but if the class doesn't exist it keeps searching the DOM, I want it to stop searching after 10 seconds. Please help master coders?

Comment: Increment a variable every iteration and `clearInterval` when it reaches 5?

Comment: use set timeout simple

Comment: Check the returns before using, program defensively and always check the return before using!

Comment: Gain access over the scripts you do execute on your page. Hook to the one call that will append this element and trigger your callback from there. You should never  have to poll for such event in production code, it's barely legit for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips guys, I am new to programming and your tips are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter and clear the timer when the counter reaches the limit:

```
var counter = 1;
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
      if ($(".discount__value")[1]) {
        $(".cart-subtotal-wrapper").append("<div class='newTotalLabel'><span class='label'>Total on Check Out</span> <span class='value'>$" + discountedTotal + "</span></div>");

        clearInterval(checkExist);
      } else {
        if (counter === 5) {
          clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
        counter++;
      }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help  ,Use set timeout for 10 seconds

```
var checkExist = setTimeout(function(){setTimeoutsetInterval(function() {
                if ($(".discount__value")[1]) {
                    $(".cart-subtotal-wrapper").append("<div class='newTotalLabel'><span class='label'>Total on Check Out</span> <span class='value'>$"+discountedTotal+"</span></div>");

                clearInterval(checkExist);
            } else { 
                console.log("retry");
            }
        }, 2000);   }, 10000);
```